# Не добавляются item в combobox

Tags: c#, wpf

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.ComboBox.Items.Add("Выйти из приложения");
}
```

При загрузке окна  все это срабатывает как обработчик для события Loaded
XLM:

```
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
```

но никакого эффекта, ComboBox - остается пустым и элемент не добавляется.

Comment: Где тело метода `Window_Loaded`?

Comment: обновил - исправил ошибку, но проблема осталась

Comment: Что вам мешает в XAML разместить этот айтем?

Comment: вообщем - ничего, но возникла проблема, хотел разобраться - что бы в будущем не возникало вопросов

Comment: если хотите разобраться, то разберитесь с MVVM (вроде как вам уже не раз советовали) и вопросов как делать эту шляпу у вас возникать не будет.